# ListVIew reorganizing unexpectedly

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview

The items in my list view and reorganizing themselves unexpectedly. Meaning when I scroll down the same list item is shown. This is very odd behavior. Has anyone encountered this?

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = view;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

       ......
       //this view is on xml file (container)
       LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.listViewControllers);


       //adding my own views to a linear layout container dynamically...
       .......
       }



    }
   return row;
```

I decided to inflate another list item view inside my getView using the inflater. all inside a for loop. However I'm having problems setting the text for my textview. Rows after first does not want to set Text properly.

Here is a code snippet inside getView

```
for(Controller aController : controllers) {   

          inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, ll, true);
          TextView tv2 = (TextView) row2.findViewWithTag("controller_name");
          tv2.setText(aController.getName());
       }
```

Here is list_view_item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_controller_cell"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowBatchController"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:tag="controller_name"
android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance. Still looking as to why the list item is not setting Text properly on "controller_name" text view

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code but you are probably using `convertView` wrong.

Comment: Are you drawing your own items in the list? The views are reused for different rows

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: yes i'm creating my own elements on the fly, i've added the code in my list view adapter

Comment: I've updated code snippets

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, `ListView` reuses list items which goes offscreen to show visible items. Add 'else' branch which doesn't inflate new `View`, but fills existing one with item data.

Comment: i'm not using an xml file to inflate my list items. I'm creating the views dynamically. So how would that work? The list item xml file just contains a Linear layout I use to inject the dynamic views that make up the row

Comment: It doesn't matter. The same view you have created for one item may be passed to you to show another item.